# WordPress-based website not working properly when viewed in China

Tags: jquery, wordpress, great-firewall-of-china

I have a fully-developed WordPress site containing a few animations and carousel. I found out that the animations and carousels do not load when it is accessed in China:

- Website does not work well when **accessed in China** using its most popular
  broswer, Baidu.
- Website works fine when **accessed in China** but using VPN to use **IP Address from other countries**.
- Website does not work well when the website is **accessed outside China** but **using China IP Address**.

The elements are in the markup but not visible. I suspect the scripts were blocked by China's firewall but there are no logs in the browser's console.

The website is hosted in the US. Also, I verified that my site is not blocked in China servers using http://www.blockedinchina.net/ and other similar tools.

Has anyone encountered the same issue? How can this be resolved aside from also hosting in China?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are there any external resources thats being loaded? e.g. Files being loaded via CDN.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your script use some urls blocked from China. This could be done by using firefox developer tool when load all the necessary urls.